how to implement url launcher for facebook?
In my Flutter app, I am implementing feature like-
There will be a button, and if user hit that button, it will take user to specific facebook profile for communicating through Facebook. I have implemented through url_launche, but it's not working. It's showing the error -
Could not launch the URL.
here you go with my code:
Future<void> launchFacebookProfile(String profileId) async {
    final Uri fbUri = Uri.parse('fb://profile/$profileId'); // Facebook app
    final Uri webUri = Uri.parse('https://www.facebook.com/$profileId'); // Fallback web URL

    try {
      if (await canLaunchUrl(fbUri)) {
        // Open the Facebook app
        await launchUrl(fbUri, mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication);
      } else if (await canLaunchUrl(webUri)) {
        // Fallback to opening in a web browser
        await launchUrl(webUri, mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication);
      } else {
        throw 'Could not launch Facebook profile';
      }
    } catch (e) {
      CustomSnack.warningSnack(e.toString());
    }
  }

Here you go with the provided link-
https://www.facebook.com/userID
Here you go with AndroidMenifext.xm file intent:
<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="whatsapp" android:host="send" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="https" />
            </intent-filter>

Please help me to solve the issue and implement the feature. Thanks in advance.

I implemented it natively with MethodChannel without using url_launcher.
androi - kotlin
IOS - swift
Connect native code with MethodChannel in flutter.
final platform = const MethodChannel("your_method_channel_key");

  openBrowser(String url) async {

    Map<String, String> args = {
      "url": url   //your url
    };

    await platform.invokeMethod("openBrowser", args);
  }

Now let's open the URL in native code.
kotlin
if(methodCall.method == "openBrowser"){
                val arguments = methodCall.arguments as? Map<String, String>
                val url = arguments?.get("url")

                if (url != null) {
                    val browserIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url))
                    startActivity(browserIntent)

                    result.success(true)
                } else {
                    result.error("INVALID_ARGUMENTS", "URL is required", null)
                }
            }

swift
if methodCall.method == "openBrowser" {
              if let args = methodCall.arguments as? [String: String],
                 let urlString = args["url"],
                 let url = URL(string: urlString) {
                  
                  UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
                  result(true)
              } else {
                  result(FlutterError(code: "INVALID_ARGUMENT", message: "Invalid URL", details: nil))
              }
          }

Please refer to the method channel documentation.
